# Programatically enable Free Shipping and set minimum order ammount for it

Tags: magento-1.7, configuration, shipping-methods, installation, install-script

I am writing a custom module, which deals with order creation, for
 multiple stores with free-shipping disabled.

What should I call in my install scripts or add to my config.xml in order to enable shipping_method == freeshipping_freeshipping and set it's minimum order amount to 0 ?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do the following in your setup script to enable free shipping.

```
$installer->setConfigData('carriers/freeshipping/active', true);
$installer->setConfigData('carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal', 0);
```

Where the installer is of type `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using install which is update this free shipping method details using

```
$groups=array();
$groups[freeshipping][fields][active][value]=true; 
$groups[freeshipping][fields][free_shipping_subtotal][value]=0
```

here `[freeshipping][fields][active][value]` is field name .you can  see this in 
here `freeshipping` is `shipping method` code and `active` is field `name of activation`

**from admin input field**

```
Mage::getModel('adminhtml/config_data')
    ->setSection('carriers')
    ->setWebsite(null)
    ->setStore($StoreId)
    ->setGroups($groups)
    ->save();
```

if you have multi store then you need fetch all store  and run this code in foop

see more at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474039/magento-update-store-logo-programmatically

Comment: Thank you, very much for the answer, Mr. Bera.
Unfortunately some IRL changes, prevented me from implementing what was going to be a golden-plating functionality for the said client. Regardless I will test the solution at 1st available opportunity and accept the answer. Thanks again.